# Uniform and const in GLSL; Unity Shader

Tags: opengl, unity-game-engine, glsl

I'm writing shaders in GLSL for Unity and I've come across a quirk that I can't find an explanation for:

In a ShaderLab SubShader Pass, I have declared vec3s within GLSLPROGAM ENDPROGRAM and outside the main function

```
const vec3 binomial_offsets = vec3(0.0, 1.3846153846, 3.2307692308);
const vec3 binomial_weights = vec3(0.2270270270, 0.3162162162, 0.0702702703);
```

This compiles fine.
However, when I replace const with uniform, for example:

```
uniform vec3 binomial_offsets = vec3(0.0, 1.3846153846, 3.2307692308);
uniform vec3 binomial_weights = vec3(0.2270270270, 0.3162162162, 0.0702702703);
```

Unity complains with:

```
GLSL shader load error (stage 1 shader 40):
ERROR: 0.40: Initializer not allowed
```

Can someone please tell me what the difference between uniform and const are in the context of GLSL (I'm familiar with the const qualifier in C/C++)

I'm trying to implement a gaussian blur by the way, if anyone is interested

Comment: which version of GLSL are you using? Initializers for uniforms are valid from GLSL 1.20 (http://ogltotd.blogspot.co.uk/2007/12/default-uniform-values.html)

Comment: no idea. Whichever version is the default I guess. I never tried playing around with some of the version macros

Comment: @GuyRT I tried the version specification, but Unity complains: `GLSL shader load error (stage 1 shader 43): ERROR: 0.108: " : #version must occur before any other statement in the program`. I have it just under GLSLPROGRAM so I'm not quite sure where the 'first statement' in the program is then?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Unity. I guess it does some manipulation of the GLSL source before compiling it (perhaps prepending its own version directive).

Comment: @GuyRT Potentially. I'm still seeking answers on the interwebs

Answer (score -1):

You can't initialise uniforms in GLSL. Uniform is different than const. Uniform must take values from your c++/unity program

Comment: This is not true. As @GuyRT already pointed out in a comment above, uniforms can be initialized in GLSL code starting with GLSL 1.20, which was released in 2006.

Comment: @CrSe As reto has pointed out, they can indeed be initialized in GLSL. Is this therefore an issue in Unity? I'm afraid I can't accept this answer on this basis